# Retries in Node.js got return HTTP 504

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-status-code-504, node.js-got

I am running http server which always returns 504:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('I AM HERE');
    res.status(504).send('Not found!!');
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000!'))
```

After that, I'm doing request, using [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#retries) with 5 retries:

```
const got = require('got');

(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await got('http://localhost:3000/', {retries: 5});
        console.log(response.body);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response.body);
    }
})();
```

I'm expecting, that inscription `I AM HERE` would be logged 5 times, but it logged only once. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `got()` only retries when there are network errors (e..g failure to reach the server or DNS failure).  A 504 status is a successful contact of the server that returns a 504 status and thus does not retry automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is retry not retries,Here is the working example

```
try {
    const response = await got('https://example.com', {retry: 2});
    return response.body
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.body);   
    return error
 }
```